# MultiUserChat get chat room user?

Tags: asmack

I am working on ASmack.
Is it workable to get chat room user list using asmack?
http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html
This list have not shown. Please give me some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which list?

You can only call [`getOccupants()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#getOccupants%28%29) if you are an occupant of the MUC or, in other words, if have joined the MUC.

Comment: I am calling getOccupants() but it's not returning occupants list all time. according to my problem i asked one Question in SO look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335872/how-to-get-list-of-occupants-from-room-in-multiuserchat , and tell me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

[getOccupants()](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#getOccupants%28%29) doesnt work for me. So you can try the code below:

```
 try {         
       ServiceDiscoveryManager discoManager =  ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConn);
       DiscoverItems discoItems = discoManager.discoverItems(roomJID);
       Iterator<DiscoverItems.Item> occupants = discoItems.getItems();  

     } catch (XMPPException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();                
     }
```

Comment: I am using 4.1.0 rc1 and i am not able to get occupants by getOccupants().
ServiceDiscoveryManager works for me.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get the List Of user's available in the Chat Room Of XMPP by the Simple Following Method passing the Parameter as MultiUserChat Object.

```
public static List<String> findMulitUser(MultiUserChat muc) {
    List<String> listUser = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> it = muc.getOccupants();
    // Traverse the chat room name
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        // Chat room members name
        String name = StringUtils.parseResource(it.next());
        System.out.println("Name Of Occupants------>" + name);
        listUser.add(name);
    }
    return listUser;
}
```